# Trigonometric operation of complex number in matrix representation

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions

I know that a complex number of form a+ib can be represented by a 2x2 matrix i.e. [a b;-b a]. They are isomorphic for basic arithmetic operation +,-,x,/.

I wonder how does one perform trigonometric operation using the matrix representation?

Obviously sin(1+2i) is not the same as simply taking sin([1 2;-2 1]).

Can someone familiar in this area enlighten me a bit please?

Comment: Perhaps some better tags to start with (frankly, I don't know which in particular, but I know some better tags exist)

Comment: Define the sine of matrix through the power series of sine (sin(M)=M-M^3/3!+...) and you will see that it works.

Comment: And note that if M is diagonalizable by an invertible matrix V, i.e. VMV^{-1}=D, where D is a diagonal matrix, then sin(M)=Vsin(D)V^{-1}, where in sin(D) you can simply take the sine of the diagonal entries.

Comment: yes, using taylor series for instance. I guess my mistake is I cannot take  independent operation for each entry of the matrix.

Comment: @ Zoltan, isn't it V^{-1}MV=D?

Comment: @cylee, Hi, I used the convention VMV^{-1}=D. And from this V^{-1}MV=D doesn't follow in general.

Comment: @cyclee, So for example you could try to find V for your matrix (actually you can try to find a unitary V), that is you should find a unitary that  diagonalizes your 2x2 matrix. (And then follow the above recipe.)

Comment: There is a whole lot of theory on performing 'holomorphic functions' on 'matrices'. See spectral theory and Dunford-Schwartz.

Comment: @Zoltan Zimboras, do you mind to elaborate a little bit more on why sin(M)=Vsin(D)V^{-1}? i.e., what is the argument to get from M=V(D)V^{-1} to sin(M)=Vsin(D)V^{-1} ?

Comment: @cylee, one could just as well ask how one performs trigonometric operations on complex numbers since they are not angles.  Taylor series allow us to transform the trig functions into algebraic ones, which we can then use to compute other types of numerical objects.